# How I can change shape of Tfidf vector (csr_matrix)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I have a bunch of documents from which I create TfIdf matrix (through TfidfVectorizer)

```
vect = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=get_stop_words(), lowercase=True, dtype=np.float32)
matrix = vect.fit_transform(list_of_documents)
```

After that I create some vectors for users

```
user_vector = matrix[index_of_document]
```

That I'm comparing user vector to matrix vectors to find similarities.

```
cosine_similarities = linear_kernel(user_vector, matrix).flatten()
```

But I have a problem. When a new document adds to this bunch I recreate matrix and its shape changes, but shape of user vectors still the same so I can't compare it anymore.

Is there any way to change shape of those vectors?

Comment: Please check out [mcve]. Try to give a small example, that shows the problem.

Comment: I try to show the problem, hope it'll help.

Comment: Can't you recreate the vectors?  Sounds like there's a size change.  In `numpy/scipy` `reshape` does not allow for a change in total number of elements.

Comment: I can't recreate them, because I changes them according to user feedback (something like machine learning). Maybe there is a way to fill vector with additional 0 to get it to the right shape.

Comment: I just have thought that I can create an empty vector with right shape and fill it with user vector data, maybe it'll work.

Comment: The shape of the output of `fit_transform` will change when new words are included in your documents. If you want to compare two sets of documents you can either call `fit_transform` on both and then compare or you can call `fit` on one set and then `transform` on the other and then compare this way.